# Wordpress Order By "Rand" - same results everytime with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

**EDIT:** I have found the issue. I have a plugin that makes ordering the posts possible in the backend. It prevents random ordered posts in the ajax call

I'm requesting a bunch of random posts via AJAX, but the result are always the same results. Do the Ajax requests get cached somehow or am I missing something?

My response header shows `Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0` in the developer console, so I'm guessing it must have something to do with wordpress?

```
function loadmore() {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
  );

  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  $i = 1;
  $posts = array();

  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
      $post = $the_query->the_post();

      $categories = get_the_category(); 
      $cat_name = $categories[0]->cat_name;

      $posts[] = array(
        'permalink' => get_permalink(),
        'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail($post, 'square-medium'),
        'post_format' => get_post_format(),
        'preview_bg' => get_field('preview_bg'),
        'preview_text' => get_field('preview_text'),
        'preview_color' => get_field('preview_color'),
        'smaller_quote' => get_field('smaller_quote'),
        'cat_name' => $cat_name,
        'title' => get_the_title(),
      );

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
  endif;


    wp_send_json($posts);
    die();
}
```

My AJAX call looks like this:

```
  $.ajax({
  url: loadrandom.ajaxurl,
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    action: 'loadmore'
  },
  success: function( result ) {
  // do something
  }});
```

Comment: plugins can keep this from working properly. Try disabling ALL plugins and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can pass one more parameter in your argument  like

```
    remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
        $args = array(
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'order'    => 'ASC'
        );
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Didn't help :( Strangely it does work on my local MAMP instance but on two servers I've tried it doesn't...